Ubuntu 24.04 on VMware 17 Pro gets stuck on boot screen
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on VMware 17 Pro, however whenever I reboot it gets stuck on the following screen:

[OK] Started systemd-logind.service User Login Management. 
[OK] Finished sysstat.service -Resets System Activity Logs. 
Starting NetworkManager.service Network Manager...
Starting wpa_supplicant.service WPA supplicant... [
[OK] Started switcheroo-control.service Switcheroo Control Proxy service. 
[OK] Finished grub-common. service -Record successful boot for GRUB. 
[OK] Finished e2scrub_reap. service Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots. 
[OK] Started avahi-daemon. service Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack. 
Starting grub-initrd-fallback.service GRUB failed boot detection... 
[OK] Started rsyslog.service System Logging Service. 
[OK] Started polkit. service Authorization Manager. 
[OK] Finished grub-initrd-fallback. service GRUB failed boot detection. Starting ModemManager. service Modem Manager...
[OK] Started power-profiles-daemon. service Power Profiles daemon. 
[OK]Started accounts-daemon. service Accounts Service. 
[OK] Started wpa_supplicant. service WPA supplicant.
Starting systemd-hostnamed. service Hostname Service... 
[OK] Finished apport.service automatic crash report generation. 
[OK] Started ModemManager.service Modem Manager. 
[OK] Finished gpu-manager.service Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes. 
[OK] Started systemd-hostnamed. service Hostname Service.
Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher. service Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service... 
[OK] Started udisks2. service -Disk Manager.
Started NetworkManager-dispatcher.service Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service. 
Listening on systemd-rfkill. socket -Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch. 
Starting systemd-rfkill. service Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Starting bluetooth. service Bluetooth service...
[OK] Started systemd-rfkill. service Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status. 
Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c12 length: 2<3
[OK] Started bluetooth.service Bluetooth service. 
[OK] Reached target bluetooth. target Bluetooth Support. 
Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c12 failed:-38
[OK] Started snapd. service Snap Daemon.
[OK] Started umware-tools.service-LSB: UMware Tools service.
Starting systemd-timedated. service -Time Date Service...
[OK] Started NetworkManager.service Network Manager.
[OK] Reached target network. target Network.
Starting NetworkManager-wait-online.service Network Manager Wait Online... Starting cups.service CUPS Scheduler...
Starting openupn. service -OpenVPN service...
Starting systemd-user-sessions. service Permit User Sessions... 
[OK]Started unattended-upgrades. service -Unattended Upgrades Shutdown. 
[OK]Finished openupn. service OpenVPN service. 
[OK]Finished systemd-user-sessions. service -Permit User Sessions. 
Starting gdm.service GNOME Display Manager...
Starting plymouth-quit-wait.service Hold until boot process finishes up... 
[OK] Started systemd-timedated.service Time Date Service. 
[OK] Started cups. service CUPS Scheduler. 
[OK] Started gdm. service GNOME Display Manager. 

I tried shutting down and rebooting several times, but each time it remains on this screen for over an hour, and I can't enter the system.

Please edit the question and add a description of what the screen shows. Is it some kind of error message?

If you do a Google search as I just did you will see this is an issue with VMware not ready for Ubuntu 24.04  My search was  -is vmware 17 ready for ubuntu 24.04-

Thanks. I've searched but it appears that this might not be the same issue.

I searched for hours on the same problem with Ubuntu 24.04 guest running in VMWare 17 on Windows 11 host. Upgrading to VMWare Workstation Pro 17.6.1 did not solve the problem. Every guest reboot hangs on the screenshot with last message [OK] Started gdm. service GNOME Display Manager. and no desktop login screen.
The following procedure solved my boot problem, inspired by:
Boot hangs when starting gdm.service

Go into recovery mode (Repeat pressing ESC during Guest startup to open Grub bootmenu)
Open root shell prompt
Type: sudo apt purge gdm gdm3
Restart to normal boot (The desktop does not start yet)
Press Ctrl+Alt+F6 and login to this shell
Type:

sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop 
sudo systemctl restart gdm


Now the desktop should return.

Note: I still don't know the root cause.
